# Bypass Required Field Missing error when Bulk Updating Opportunity Stage Name to Closed Lost

Tags: opportunity, data-loader, stagename, updaterecord

When bulk updating old Opportunities to 'Closed Lost'  via Data Loader, some records failed to update with following error -

```
Required fields are missing: [Custom_PickListField__c]
```

How can i bypass this error, and update the Opportunity records to 'Closed Lost' ?

Note: These Open Opportunities have a close date way back in the past. Seems like these were created before the Custom_PickListField__c was made required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to alter the validation rule so that it passes, or provide values to match the conditions. Altering the formula rule might be done by adding a rule for the CreatedDate (e.g. `CreatedDate < DATE(2019, 1, 31)` ). For "Required" fields set at the database level, you need to either provide a value, or remove the Required flag from the field's properties.

Comment: There is no validation rule on Opportunity.

Comment: @user4947 Oh, so you have a globally required field? You'll need to provide a value for each record, or turn off the required flag.

Comment: If i turn off the the required flag temporarily, to be able to chnage the status to 'Closed Lost', and then turn ON the Required flag, would there be any repercussions. ?

Comment: @user4947 The only possible problem is that users would be able to save records without this required field during that time. You may want to make it required on the page layout, but optional at the database level. This will keep UI users from bypassing your intent while you make this update.